# How to check if series is hidden when a user clicks on legend in ApexCharts

Tags: apexcharts

I'm using a stacked bar chart with ApexCharts. It is default functionality from ApexChart that clicking on an item in the legend hides that series in the graph. I have annotations that only make sense when all series are shown, so I want to hide these annotations when a user clicks on an item in the legend.

I am currently trying a solution where I listen to the `legendClick` event, but I'm not sure how to determine if one series is currently hidden.

Answer (score 1):

```
legendClick: (chartContext, seriesIndex, config)=>{ 
 if(config.config.series[seriesIndex]){
   console.log('toggle series: ' + config.config.series[seriesIndex].name)
   if(config.config.series[seriesIndex].data.length){
      // series is being hidden
   } else {
      // series is being shown
   }
 }
}
```

In the legendClick handler, the context & config both contain the series data.

If a series is disabled on the legend, its data is an empty array in the context/config.

If the series matching the clickedIndex is empty we can detect wether being shown or hidden.